# Angular: Load value from asset text file

Tags: angular, file-io, assets

I have two text files in my assets folder that I'm using to store important keys: apiKey.txt, and appId.txt. These both contain just plain text

I'm using the http client to retrieve them but they're still registering as undefined. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
//import { iDynamicsPostUsers } from '../models/dynamics-post';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AirtableService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/';
  protected apiKey: string;
  protected appId: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('assets/apiKey.txt', { responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => { this.apiKey = data });
    this.http.get('assets/appId.txt', { responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => { this.appId = data });
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. You definitely should check the DevTools Network Tab and try out the URL directly in the browser, e. g. `http://localhost:4200/assets/apiKey.txt`.

Comment: Ya the url works when I try it directly in the browser. Still showing up as undefined in my angular app though

Comment: What does the DevTools Network Panel say? Does it show the right request? Do you use any interceptors for the HttpClient?

Comment: Network panel shows 3 calls to each file with all of them returning 304. The responses show the correct returned values but still undefined in the angular app

Comment: I really do not know what does not work for you. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lrv3ra

Answer (score 0):

I use FileReader:

```
this.http.get('assets/faq.txt', { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' })
  .subscribe((value: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
    const data = new Blob([value.body as Blob], {type: value.body?.type});
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(data);

    reader.onload = (content) => {
      const textInFile = reader.result as string;
    };
  });
```

@Darkreaper it is a pity but in this case you could not. It`s can be released in this way.

At first you load file from assets or remote server. You can incapsulate this logic inside service or in component, never mind.

```
  public downloadFile(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get('assets/faq.txt', { responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' })
      .pipe((file:  HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
        return new Blob([value.body as Blob], {type: value.body?.type});
      });
  }
```

And in component you can use it with file reader:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.downloadFile(url)
      .subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(blob);

        reader.onload = () => {
          this.componentVar = reader.result;
        };
      });
```

When file was downloaded file reader read it content and update component property with file content.

Comment: How would I structure this as a function then where I could pass in the filename and have it return an Observable<string> containing the textInFile?

Comment: Get an error of "Argument of type '(value: HttpResponse<Blob>) => Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<Blob>, Blob>'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'source' are incompatible." on the following section
.pipe((file:  HttpResponse<Blob>) => {